# Parse Email Headers that have have EOL stripped

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I am working on a JS/JQuery based tool to review and analyze Internet Email Headers. The tools I have created before have relied on the presence of a New Line delimiter. From time to time, I get a customer that has sent in Internet Headers that have been Copy and Pasted enough times that the `\r\n` or `\n` and no longer read. Often substituted by `\s\s` or just `\s`. Hence there become no simple, or good way to find each of the lines.

That is exactly what I am trying to do. Given Internet Headers that may or may not contain the proper EOL, how can I capture all the lines or capture the various elements (`Received:`, `X-Headers:`, `Message-ID:`, `To:`, `From:`, `Subject:`, `Date:`).

Here is a Fiddle I have been working on: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0n5tmm6L/

**Snippet**

```
  $("#clean-header").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#header-1").val() === "") {
      $("#error").html("No headers submitted.");
      return false;
    }
    $("#error").html("");
    var textLines = $("#header-1").val().split('\n');
    if (textLines.length > 1) {
      console.log("Found " + textLines.length + " Lines ('\\n') in  headers.");
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("No EOL found in Headers. Seeking 'Received:'.");
      var s1 = /(Received):\s?from\s(.+?)\s(by.+?);\s(.+?,\s[0-9]{2}\s[a-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.+?)\s{2}/ig;
      var match, received = [];
      var line = $("#header-1").val();
      while (match = s1.exec(line)) {
        received.push({
          "from": match[2],
          "by": match[3],
          "stamp": match[4]
        });
      }
      console.log("Found ", received.length, " Received Lines.");
    }
  });
```

I'm not afraid to push this to PHP with Pear and use the IMAP library to do this. I was just hoping to do it in the browser without having to involve the server.

In the absence of `\n`, I was hoping to make a few passes with regular expressions like the following:

```
/(Received):\s?(from.+?)\s(by.+?);\s(.+?,\s[0-9]{2}\s[a-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.+?)\s{2}/ig
/(X-.+?):(.+?)\s\s/ig
/(Reply-To|Return-Path|From):.+?<(.+?)>\s{2}/ig
/(To):.+?<(.+?)>\s{2}/ig
```

I never know if what the EOL will be, if anything. I have also hunted to see if there are any good add-ons or libraries that already do this. So far, not seen any. Suggestions greatly welcome. Alternatives also welcome.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so like: `/(X-[^]+?):\s?([^]+?)\s{2}/ig` so it's not so greedy?

Comment: Sorry, removed previous comment. I suggested using `[\s\S]` or `[^]` to match *any* character incl. *any* newline. The `.` does not match a newline.

Comment: Which would be helpful if `\r\n` or `\n` existed in the string. Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: If you minimize the example I think you'd get an answer quicker. I suspect you could use a tempered greedy token Iif you need to match the shortest window between some delimiters.